# change image in jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jdbc

How to change the image in the label by click on table's row?

I have some code. First one is action listener from `jtable`.

```
private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    //jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    Database base =  new Database();
    model =  (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
    int selectedRowIndex = jTable2.getSelectedRow();

    //find picture in forlder and change jLabel2 for image 
    base.findImageDerictory(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString(), jLabel2 );
}
```

After that, I am trying to get my picture from the folder, but the problem the picture switch so slow.

```
public void findImageDerictory(String name, JLabel jLabel2){
    String pictureName = null;

    try
    {
        data = getmyConnection();
        st = data.createStatement();
        myResults = st.executeQuery( "SELECT Picture  FROM students_center WHERE  Name = '" + name + "'" );

        while ( myResults.next() )
        {
            //COPY PATH IN pictureName 
            pictureName = myResults.getString( 1 );
        }
        //SWITH TO ANOTHER PICTURE
        File sourceFile = new File( pictureName );

        ImageIcon imageIcon;
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "/newdatabase/images/" + sourceFile.getName() ) );
        Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); // transform it
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance( 220, 220, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ); // scale it the smooth way
        imageIcon = new ImageIcon( newimg );
        jLabel2.setIcon( imageIcon );

        myResults.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"problem the picture switch so slow*" ... you're connecting to a database, performing a query, loading a file from the file system and scaling the icon ... why do you think it would be fast?

Comment: This `File sourceFile = new File(pictureName);` and `imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newdatabase/images/"+sourceFile.getName()));` seems pointless (and possibly error prone)

Comment: `while (myResults.next()) {` Why? Wouldn't the first result be enough? You've also not taking into account what happens if no image is available

Comment: How to change this mistake? Any ideas?

Comment: Plenty, but I doubt it will help improve the performance by much

Comment: I think it's possible to avoid calling into the database every time. Maybe I can check the name of image in folder?

Comment: Well, since you seem to be getting the images as embedded resources, there are only ever going to be a limited number.  And yes, you, should be caching previous results, especially since you're scaling them